# How to get sufficient current out of two parallel DC/DC power supplies?

Tags: integrated-circuit, switching-regulator, dual-supply

I have two [RT8299AZSP](https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT8299A/DS8299A-03.pdf) (24V adjustable DC/DC switching regulators) chips connected in parallel. They are each rated for 3A, and provide the power to drive a high power UV LED (can't say too much about that, just that I am confident the driver consumes a max of 5A). I am having trouble sourcing current levels of around 3.3A and higher. This led me to find that when two parallel power sources have even small differences in their output voltages, one of them takes over the current output and the other becomes functionally idle. I believe that this is the problem I am having, given data collected from exhaustive testing. I have two questions about this: 1) Can someone explain a bit better why this happens, or link a good resource where I can find out more? I tried and can't find a ton of material on it. 2) Is there a way I can solve this issue on my PCB? My first thought was to directly connect the FB pin of the two ICs together before their voltage divider circuits, but I don't understand enough about the internal circuitry - specifically the PGOOD/VCC circuit - to tell if that would actually equalize everything.

What I am seeing is the LED working fine as the brightness increases and the current nears 3A, but as we increase more and hit ~3.3A the LED shuts off after some time in the order of 10s. I am now doing testing of leaving the LED on at a lower brightness for a long time but don't have those results yet. My hypothesis is that one of the RT8299s is providing most of the current so when we drive it close to its maximum for a time it overheats and goes into thermal shutdown, which is why the LED is turning off but the regulator is not blowing up. If I could get the other regulator on the PCB to supply current as well this issue would be eliminated.

I have checked the traces several times over and am confident that the board design and accompanying output wires are capable of providing around 10A.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRJGvd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Use two diodes on the outputs and adjust the feedback resistors to generate an extra 500mv to compensate for the diodes?

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding a 0.22 ohm resistor in series with each output. This will make a 0.22 ohms x 3amp = 0.66v drop across the resistor but create a 0.66v "shock absorber" for each unit and should decouple their ability to "see" the other unit. Each resistor should be 3 to 5W devices.

Comment: This makes sense to me. I may play around with the values obviously but I get the point and can see why it would help. What do you mean by "shock absorber"? Outside of abstracting the regulators from each other, would they serve another function?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a load share controller.  This is a separate chip for each module that senses how much current it's providing (usually through a shunt resistor) and adjusts the voltage output of each converter so that they share equally (i.e. droop regulation).  You will probably be able to use the FB pin on your existing converters to accomplish this but you'll need to examine the datasheet of whichever controller you choose to see how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

> one of them takes over the current output and the other becomes functionally idle

Yes, the one with higher voltage will drive the load while the other idles... and when output current increases over what one buck can supply, it will shut down.

Here's a simple solution:

Treat each buck as independent, with its own output caps and feedback taken on them. Their output voltages should be quite close, otherwise adjust the feedback resistors.

Then, add 0.1 ohm resistors at the output of each, in order to parallel them.

Feedback has to be taken on the buck output caps, before the resistor, not after.

Voltage drop over the resistors will help them share the load. This increases losses, of course, so you want a resistor that is just high enough, so its voltage drop covers the difference between the output voltages that both converters want.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand how this works. The output voltage at each resistor - before going through them - will be somewhere around 12.3V. Then they go through a small resistor. Depending on the current pull of the LED, there will be a 50-300mV drop through the resistor (assuming 0.1ohms, current range between 1-6A). Assuming my understanding so far is correct, on a lower level how does this cause the voltages to match up, and how does it cause sourced current from each?

Comment: My best guess is that it allows a way for each regulator to use current to drop voltage and get to a common level, through which they are necessarily both using significant enough current. Which makes sense, so actually my previous question on this thread is more of a lack of understanding of the initial problem and why this solution solves it, rather than why the solution works.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea: use current to drop voltage and get to a common level. There are better and more accurate ways to do it, but all of them are much more complicated than just two resistors.